# Error from import android.R or from layout.main?

Tags: android

I keep either removing import.R or adding mypackage.R or deleting all imports and shift-control O
or deleting R.java.

I still get the error: main.xml cannot be resolved or alternately, R cannot be resolved to a variable. I have cleaned each time. How do you get this to work?

```
   package com.hga;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.Button;

   public class Hga extends Activity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView( R.layout.activity_hga );
```

Comment: More background info will be needed im afraid

Comment: Sometimes there is an error in a XML file which causes this kind of error. Check all your XML files and make sure, hat they are error free.

Comment: Is R being generated to begin with? Does `activity_hga` have an xml name of `activity_hga.xml`?

Comment: Sometimes the XML layouts don't tell you what the error is, or it's too vague to help. In that case try looking at the error log by going to Window->Show View->Error Log

Answer (score 0):

Yeah i used to run into those type of problems when i was starting programing for android. The  R folder updates itself everytime code is written or saved and when a error occurs in your code for whatver reason it may be the R folder gives you that error report. At first clean but if that doesnt work as it usually wont you want to completely coment out your code /* .... */
then clean and the error should go way now you can pin point which bit of code is causing the error to occur in the R folder. 
PS. this was my main source of frustration in coding android apps